# do i need 32bit libxml2 for python on snow leopard?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, libxml2

i'm having a hell of a time installing scrapy on my sl mbp. it requires libxml2, so i set about installing that. installing it from macports doesn't seem to pull down the python binding.

installing it from source through scrapy's instructions ([here](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html#intro-install-step1)) does install the python bindings, but when i run 'python -c "import libxml2"' i get an architecture mismatch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "libxml2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libxml2mod
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/libxml2mod.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/libxml2mod.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

when i explicitly build the libxml2 dlls to be 32bit, that error goes away, but then libxslt won't build because of some other library not being 32 bit. i'm afraid to keep pulling on that string. so the question is - is python 32bit only? am i doing something stupid here?

*edit* - this is python 2.6

*edit 2* - by popular demand, i'm consolidating @Ned Deily's awesome answer up here. all credit to him, i'm just posting the steps i took based on his response:

if you've been screwing around with mac ports, (and haven't installed anything else through them that you need), nuke them.

```
$ sudo rm -r /opt/local
```

add the following to `/opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf` to prevent downloading the entire unix library with the next commands

```
+bash_completion +quartz +ssl +no_x11 +no_neon +no_tkinter +universal +libyaml -scientific
```

install the macports version of python

```
$ sudo port install python26
```

install the pre-reqs for scrapy

```
sudo port install py26-libxml2 py26-twisted py26-openssl py26-simplejson py26-setuptools python_select
sudo python_select python26
```

test that the correct python is selected: run `$ which python`, which should say something along the lines of '/opt/local/bin/python', and that in its own right should be a link to /opt/local/bin/python2.6.

test that the correct architectures are present: run `file 'which python'` (the single quotes should be backticks, which should spit out (for intel macs running 10.6):

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.6: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/opt/local/bin/python2.6 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/opt/local/bin/python2.6 (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

test that libxml installed successfully

```
$ python -c 'import libxml2'
```

if all is well, you should get no output.

install scrapy

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 scrapy
```

run through the streets (fully clothed) rejoicing that everything is done. again, thanks to ned for the detailed response.

Comment: You have some spaces in the path for libxml2mod is that just a cut and paste error? (As in two different places it is not obvious)

Comment: cut 'n paste error. terminal -> so 4-space-for-code-indent == spacing mayhem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the paths in your traceback, it appears you have installed and are trying to use the python.org python 2.6.4 (installed to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks` ...).  That python is 32-bit only.   By default on 10.6, MacPorts tries to install 64-bit versions of packages.  You can change that for most MacPorts packages by specfying the `+universal` variant on your MacPorts install commands or by adding it to `/opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf`.  But, since you need a variety of packages, if you just need this for your own machine you'll likely find it much easier to just install a complete python2.6 64-bit solution using MacPorts.  Other than scrapy itself, you should find nearly all of the packages you need already there.  You'll need to modify your $PATH to add `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin` and `/opt/local/bin` before any other directories with Python in them.  Something like this should work (untested!):

```
sudo port selfupdate  # ensure you have the latest ports file information
sudo port install py26-libxml2 py26-twisted py26-openssl py26-simplejson py26-setuptools python_select
sudo python_select python26  # optionally make /opt/local/bin/python -> python2.6
sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 scrapy
# or install manually
cd /path/to/scrapy
sudo /opt/local/bin/python2.6 setup.py install
```

EDIT: For 10.6, due to some issues with lack of Tk support in 64-bit mode, Tk defaults to the X11 version which you probably neither want nor need.  I add the following variants to `/opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf` for 10.6 (not all of them are applicable to python and friends):

```
+bash_completion +quartz +ssl +no_x11 +no_neon +no_tkinter +universal +libyaml -scientific
```

EDIT:  If MacPorts is installed properly, you should see something like this on 10.6:

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  73 Oct 28 20:25 /opt/local/bin/python2.6@ -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
$ file /opt/local/bin/python2.6
/opt/local/bin/python2.6: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/opt/local/bin/python2.6 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/opt/local/bin/python2.6 (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

That's if you've added the `+universal` variant, otherwise you may just see a single x86_64 or i386 architecture.

When using relative paths, make sure your shell $PATH has the two MacPorts directories first:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin ...
```

You may need to edit your `~/.bash_profile` or other shell file to make that change "permanent".  If you want the bare `python` command to refer to the MacPorts Python, make sure to run the `python_select` command shown above.  If you are still having problems, a nice thing about MacPorts is it is easy to delete and start over again; just:

```
$ sudo rm -r /opt/local
```

and download the MacPorts 10.6 installer.  But you really shouldn't have to do that.  And I think it would really be in your best interests to get this fixed and working as it will likely save you lots of headaches in the future.

Comment: although i have to say, that port install is bringing down all of system 5. ugh. wtf does x11 have to do with python!?@. bah!

Comment: on closer inspection... python26 from mp is 32bit. it's the same 10/27/09 build that i already had, and isn't 32bit. unless i'm doing something way wrong.

Comment: Sorry about the pulling in x11. I've updated the answer to include specifying some variants to prevent that in 10.6.  The traceback in your original question shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python....`. That's not the path for a MacPorts-installed Python.  It is for a python.org Python, among others, or build-from-source framework install.

Comment: thanks, but something is confusing port then, because it tells me that it's installed:
$ file `which python`
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python (for architecture ppc): Mach-O executable ppc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

Comment: Check your shell `$PATH` and the output of `which python` to figure out which python you are invoking.  It's very easy to get confused on OS X where it is not unusual to have multiple versions installed in different locations.  Using absolute paths can help: `/opt/local/bin/python2.6` for MacPorts, `/usr/local/bin/python2.6` for python.org, `/usr/bin/python2.6` for the Apple-supplied Python in 10.6.

Comment: ha. to make things "less" confusing, /opt/local/bin/python2.6 is a link to /Frameworks/..., which is the i386+ppc install. i'm about to say forget it and build from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, that just doesn't look right!  I've added some more suggestions to the answer.  While it's your call, of course, building from scratch is going to be a *lot* more trouble; you really should get the MacPorts issues straightened out now.

Comment: whew. all that finally did it. i nuked the macports directory, and restarted from scratch. after that things seem to have lined up. thanks!

Comment: @kolosy Any chance you could post the steps you took to get this done? The discussion is helpful, but hard to get the steps right in order from reading this thread..

Answer (score 1):

I have a small note to contribute. While attempting to follow-along on this post, I began with three installs of Python:

1. The default Apple Python 2.5.1 located at: /usr/bin/python
2. A version located: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
3. And a Macport version located: /opt/local/bin/python2.6

My trouble was that:

```
$ python
```

would always default to the 2.7 when I needed it to use the Macports version. The following did not help:

```
$ sudo python_select python26
```

I even removed the 2.7 version which caused only an error.

I figured out I needed to change the default path to the Macports version using the following:

```
$ PATH=$PATH\:/opt/local/bin ; export PATH
```

And then reinitiate the ports, etc.

Finally, I was not able to reference the scrapy-ctl.py file by default through these instructions so I had to reference the scrapy-ctl.py file directly

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/scrapy-ctl.py
```

**UPDATE**

A quick addendum to this post with instructions to create the link, found [on the Scrapy site](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html#intro-install-dev) (#2 and #3).

Starting with #2, "Add Scrapy to your Python Path"

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/scrapy-ctl.py /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy
```

And #3, "Make the scrapy command available"

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/scrapy-ctl.py /usr/local/bin/scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install but still struggling. 
When I:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 scrapy
```

I get error message and it stops

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Instead I build Scrapy from scratch which works fine.

Then I try what you write

```
cd /path/to/scrapy
sudo /opt/local/bin/python2.6 setup.py install
```

Where is /path/to/scrapy? Is that:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/scrapy-ctl.py
```

or

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.8-py2.6.egg
```

or is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Ned Deily

These steps seem to work if you want to run Scrapy 0.8 on OS X 10.6. It uses Macports install of Python 2.6 rather than the one bundled with the OS. Steps assume Macports is not installed yet.

Get latest MacPorts installer from here and install:

http://www.macports.org/install.php

```
sudo port install py26-libxml2 py26-twisted py26-openssl py26-simplejson py26-setuptools python_select

sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 scrapy
```

Change your ~.profile to:

```
export     PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```