# Error installing scrapy on Mac Os X 10.6

Tags: python, macos, libxml2, scrapy

Trying to install Scrapy on Mac OSX 10.6 using this [guide](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html):

When running these commands from Terminal:

```
cd libxml2-2.7.3/python
sudo make install
```

I get the following error:

```
Making install in .
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../libxslt/libxslt.la', needed by `libxsltmod.la'.  Stop.
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Following the first steps in the [Guide](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html), which involved building and installing the libxml2 and libxslt packages seemed to be successful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use MacPorts to [install python and the libraries you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353957/do-i-need-32bit-libxml2-for-python-on-snow-leopard/).

Comment: @Ned Thanks... I'll follow that thread.. Problem looks similar enough to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Ned Deily

These steps seem to work if you want to run Scrapy 0.8 on OS X 10.6. It uses Macports install of Python 2.6 rather than the one bundled with the OS. Steps assume Macports is not installed yet.

Get latest MacPorts installer from here and install:

http://www.macports.org/install.php

```
sudo port install py26-libxml2 py26-twisted py26-openssl py26-simplejson py26-setuptools python_select

sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 scrapy
```

Change your ~.profile to:

```
export     PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This has worked for me so far but what/where is my ~.profile?

Comment: Your .profile file is in the root of  /Users/<your_account_name> ... It's hidden in the Finder, so it's easier to navigate to via Terminal.. You can edit it with vi or eMacs..the .profile is basically the config file for your login shell...